# Track user traffic source and display a slightly customized page?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

I was wondering if there's a possibility to track where a user comes from e.g. AdWords or Referal or Facebook etc and based on this information to show a different page?

For example it would be very useful to be able to display a different contact phone or email address on your contact page to users coming from AdWords.

How do you do this?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

For instance, for adwords, you can follow the explanation in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478510/how-to-capture-if-a-visitor-is-from-a-google-adwords-click). For other systems, you can use similar mechanics. I recommend that you make a search in this forum and in StackOverflow.